# Rounding a value contained within a CString

Tags: c++, c-strings

So I have a CString which contains a number value e.g. "45.05" and I would like to round this number to one decimal place.

I use this funcion

```
_stscanf(strValue, _T("%f"), &m_Value);
```

to put the value into a float which i can round. However in the case of 45.05 the number i get is 45.04999... which rounds to 45.0 where one would expect 45.1

How can I get the correct value from my CString?

TIA

Comment: Are you calling a ceil function on the value? Or is it that the strValue has 45.0499 after calling the _stscanf?

Comment: m_Value has 45.04999 after calling

Comment: That is because of floating point representation in binary. Please read this to find out why this happens - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html or this http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/. Long story short, for floating point values, don't expect the exact value to be available - there is a small difference between the intended value and the actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a string result, your best bet is to find the decimal point and inspect the two digits after it and use them to make a rounded result.  If you need a floating-point number as a result, well.. it's hopeless since 45.1 cannot be represented exactly.

EDIT: the nearest you can come to rounding with arithmetic is computing `floor(x*10+0.5)/10`, but know that doing this with 45.05 WILL NOT and CAN NOT result in 45.1.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the digits that make up the hundredths and below positions separately, convert them to a number and round it independently, and then add that to the rest of the number:

"45.05" = 45.0 and 0.5 tenths (0.5 can be represented exactly in binary)

round 0.5 tenths to 1

45.0 + 1 tenth = 45.1

don't confuse this with just handling the fractional position separately. "45.15" isn't divided into 45 and .15, it's divided into 45.1 and 0.5 tenths.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used c++ in a while but here are the steps I would take.

1. Count the characters after the Decimal
2. Remove the Decimal
3. cast the string to an Int
4. Perform Rounding operation
5. Divide by the (number of characters less one)*10
6. Store result in a float