# Convert, multiply and round CString values in MFC C++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have two CString values:

```
CString a="40.50";
CString b="0.490";
```

I need to get CString value with two digits precision:

```
double dbl=atof(a)*atof(b);
CString k=""; k.Format("%.2f", dbl);
```

The value is "19.84", but it must be 19.85 by round procedure. Is there way to multiply, and convert value properly? I tried something like:

```
static const double powerOfTen[] = { 1.0, 10.0, 100.0 };
float dsum = atof(a) * atof(b);
dsum = std::floor(dsum * powerOfTen[2] + 0.5) / powerOfTen[2]
CString k=""; k.Format("%.2f", dsum);
```

But it doesn't always help.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790950/rounding-a-value-contained-within-a-cstring

Comment: Very useful reading, thank you. But is there a short answer for my question?

Comment: May be, there is a simple solution: dsum=double(round(dsum * 1e2) / 1e2); Using cmath...

Comment: The short answer is: Floating point values can only represent sums of powers of two. Not every decimal can be represented as a finite sum of powers of two (e.g. 0.1). If you are dealing with currency values, then simply don't use floating point values to represent them. If those are other values and you need to display them with exactly 2 decimal places, then that is a string operation.

Comment: If you want to represent "amount" - type data, floating point numbers is not a good choice. We have always used fixed-point arithmetic for these, and as general-purpose languages do not have such a built-in type, the solution is the 64-bit integer, representing the amount in cents (or the minimum denomination); this provides both the necessary range and precision. You need to write a small library though (conversions, some operations and decimal point adjustments). What you did in your last code snippet is essentially this, ie promoted the desired precision to whole-number level, which works.